# Save kafka application logs in SQL database

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka application logs are stored in a file and it gets big very soon and difficult to find something in it, so i was wondering there's some configuration to parse the logs as per our necessary and store the logs directly to the SQL db.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't have to be a file. That's just the default. Look for log4j jdbc appenders and configure it for Kafka